# undefined method `comments_path' which I can't find in the code files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the error below (NoMethodError) while trying to add a new comment to an article , the problem is that it refers to undefined method `comments_path' which I can't find in the code files

Please help

Note:
I have tried to search about this error , but results I found were not relevant also the problem is the error is pointing to something I can't find.

The error is shown below:

NoMethodError in Comments#new
Showing /home/abc/my_ruby_projects/myblog3/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `comments_path' for #<#:0x007fb57888bf28>
Did you mean?  font_path
Extracted source (around line #1):

```
<%= form_with model: @comment do |form| %>
  <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <....>
      <ul>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/comments/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/abc/.../myblog3

I have defined nested routes for articles & comments as shown below:

```
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

my routes seems correct , as shown below:

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
         rails_admin        /admin                                            RailsAdmin::Engine
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is looking for a route to which it can post the comment updates.

Your routes config likely needs something like

```
resources :comments
```

A command line call to list routes will now show you this comments_path it's looking for

```
rake routes
```

And then you'll need a CommentsController with an update method/action to handle the postback.

```
class CommentsController
  def edit
  end

  def update
    # save data
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Actually I have the resources :comments already in the routes & the controller have the actions , here the problem is with the new comment not the show comment method mainly.

Please check my updated info for the routes.rb & rails routes cmd.

Comment: Your partial seems to mix @comment with comment (no @)... is your outer view defining a comment variable, or should that also be @comment?

Comment: I think maybe you are mixing up things... your route is setup to access comments as a nested resource but your form is not. If you flatten out your route (make comments its own resource) that may work. Alternatively, you can try bang bang's approach and setup for nested attributes being saved through the article model, but I think your forn structure would need to be rethought in that case

Comment: I have changed that partial after the scaffold created it , as when I nested comments in articles I got errors with the hint (did you mean @comment)

initially it was : (in the comments partial)
`<%= form_with (model: comment, local: true) do |form| %>`

then I changed it to :
`<%= form_with @comment do |form| %>`

Comment: or keep the nested resource as is, and simply add `resources :comments` at the same level that `resources :articles`, allowing both ways.

Comment: maybe I mixing up , I am a beginner still
how to edit the form to work with these routes ?

or what is the best practice in your opinion to solve this ?
thanks

Comment: Saving one to many children through the parent form is tricky and usually involves some javascript magic for adding new rows. Having both routes is fine at least to figure things out.

Comment: @Brett :
so you mean better to remove the nesting in the routes ?

Comment: I think so given how your form setup seems to access comments directly

Comment: Thank you both very much , I will keep trying with it & update the post once solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add comments to an article I imagine you have a nested resource where an `Article` has many `comments`. Now your `/config/routes.rb` would have an entry like:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

and assuming there is `accept_nested_attributes` in your `/models.article.rb` model.

Now in your view usually your form should look something similar to:

```
<%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>
```

When routing I find it useful using the `rails routes` command, but once they grow too much instead of piping the output to `grep` I'd rather use the gem [sextant](https://github.com/schneems/sextant) in development.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I have the resources :comments already in the routes as you expected & the controller have the actions .

I don't have the accept_nested_attributes (didn't see that in the guide)

in the rails 5 , the default that I got was : (in the partial of comments , using scaffold) 

`<%= **form_with** model: @comment do |form| %>`

Please check my updated info for the routes.rb & rails routes cmd.